# rspec , undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, undefined

```
feature "comment" do
 given(:user) do
      build(:user)
 end
 background do
  user1=create(:user)
  user1.id=1
  login_as(user1)     
 end
 scenario "can create comment" do
     @undertake=create(:undertake)
     visit undertake_path(@undertake)
     within("form#undertake-form-test") do
      fill_in "content" , with: "heyheyhey"
     end
     click_button 'send-btn'
     expect(page).to have_content 'heyheyhey'
 end
end
```

This is spec/features/comment_spec.rb. and this below is controllers/undertakes_controller.rb.

```
class UndertakesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  @undertake=Undertake.find_by(id: params[:id])
   @comment=current_user.comments.new
end
```

and this below is views/undertakes/show.html.erb.

```
<p><%= @undertake.id %></p>
```

and spec/factories/undertakes.rb.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :undertake do
    association :ask
    association :user
    id 1
    user_id 2
    ask_id 1
    title "MyString"
    content "MyText"
    result false    
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :asks , except:[:edit, :update] do 
  resources :undertakes , only:[:create , :show , :destroy] , shallow: true do 
    resources :comments , only:[:create] 
  end 
end
```

Now, why do I have error `ActionView::Template::Error:undefined method id for nil:NilClass`.  Please help me.

Comment: please show your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Here is routes.rb. Please.

Comment: resources :asks , except:[:edit, :update] do
       resources :undertakes , only:[:create , :show ,  :destroy] , shallow: true do
           resources :comments , only:[:create] 
       end
   end

Comment: You should add that code to your question, not the comments.

Comment: This is happening because you are calling the method (via attribute) not on an instance of a class, but on an variable with the value "nil." You need to figure out where this is happening, my best guess is that the following line is failing somehow:  `user1=create(:user)` try adding the line `p user1` after that line, then check the log / screen to see the value of user 1. my guess is that it will be nil. Then you need to figure out why it's returning nil instead of the expected value of a instance variable.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I did , but I still have the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things going on here that could be the potential cause and which are very unidiomatic if not straight up wrong.

First off the name `undertake` is just wrong. Use the noun form [Undertaking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undertaking) instead for a model name.

Never use `find_by(id: params[:id])`. Instead use `find(params[:id])` as it will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundError` and render the 404 page if the record is not found instead of blowing up with a nil error.

```
class UndertakingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @undertaking = Undertaking.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @undertaking.comments.new
  end
end
```

Also you should be creating the comment from `@undertaking` - don't pass the user id via a form as it makes it childs play for a malicous user to spoof.

Instead assign the user from the session when creating records:

```
class CommentsController
  # this assumes you are using Devise
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is how you would write the spec idiomatically. Note the use of memoized `let` helpers and the fact that you **NEVER** assign ids to records. That is done by the database. Trying to do it manually will only mess things up.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe 'Comments' do
  let(:current_user) { create(:user) }
  let(:undertaking) { create(:undertaking) }

  background do
    login_as(current_user)
  end

  scenario "can create a comment" do
    visit undertaking_path(undertaking)
    # Avoid using CSS selectors and instead write specs
    # based on what the user sees as it makes specs brittle
    within("form#undertake-form-test") do
      fill_in "content" , with: "heyheyhey"
      click_button 'Create comment'
    end
    expect(page).to have_content 'heyheyhey' 
  end
end
```

Use `let` instead of `@instance` variables. When writing feature, request and controller specs you need to use `FactoryGirl.create` not `build` as the later does not insert into the database and the record will not actually exist in your rails application.

Also your factory definion is badly broken. The whole idea of a factory is that it should create unique, valid records. Never set ids in a factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :undertaking do
    title "MyString"
    content "MyText"
    user # just reference the factory if you REALLY need the association to exist
    ask # just reference the factory if you REALLY need the association to exist
    result false # this should probally be set through a DB default instead!
  end
end
```